# Objects can't go inside my mesh?

Tags: mesh, normals, sculpt

So I've been making a a character and I've fully sculpted, retopologized, and baked normals with this character. I then went to work on making an eye, and when i finished i tried to move the eye inside the head of the mesh, and for some reason it refuses to go inside. Every time i think i've successfully transformed it inside the eye socket, it ends up on the other side of the head altogether. It's like every time i move the eye, it's only sliding along the surface of the mesh rather than intersecting it. I don't understand what happened.

Comment: Did you happen to leave face-snapping enabled after retopologizing?

Comment: Yep that was it thanks, i totally forgot i still had snapping enabled